# Ruby function to format date

Tags: ruby, date, methods, format

I need assistance with formatting a date string. I have a JSON object which contains the elements "start_date" and "end_date". These elements contain date information in a string such as so:

```
"2015-07-15"
```

I have created this method to format my start_date and end_date:

```
def format_date(date)
  date.to_time.strftime('%b %d')
end
```

What this method does is to format the date into this format of:

```
"Jul 15"
```

This method helps me print the start_date and end_date into the form:

```
"Jul 15 to Jul 27"
```

What I want, is to have my dates formatted in the form of:

```
"15 - 27 July 2015" #If the two dates fall within the same month

"15 July - 27 Aug 2015" #If the two dates fall into separate months
```

Could anyone assist me in writing such a ruby method?

Comment: I think you have to handle several cases here: (1) same day, (2) different days but same month and year, (3) different months but same year (4) different years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def format_date(date1, date2)

  # convert the dates to time
  date1 = date1.to_time
  date2 = date2.to_time

  # Ensure date1 is the lowest
  if date1 > date2
    date1, date2 = date2, date1
  end

  # handle identical dates
  if date1 == date2
    return date1.strftime('%d %b %Y')
  end

  # handle same year
  if date1.year == date2.year

    #handle same month
    if date1.month == date2.month
      return "#{date1.strftime('%d')} - #{date2.strftime('%d %b %Y')}"

    # handle different month
    else
      return "#{date1.strftime('%d %b')} - #{date2.strftime('%d %b %Y')}"
    end
  end

  # handle different date-month-year
  return "#{date1.strftime('%d %b %Y')} - #{date2.strftime('%d %b %Y')}"
end
```

I'd start with this and refactor it into something more readable and useable for you.

Comment: Thanks a million dude! You literally saved me hours of wrecking my brain! I really appreciate it! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use formatted_times gem

https://rubygems.org/gems/formatted_times/versions/0.0.4

It helps you to format date as per your requirement